# Differentiable Functions with equality

Tags: functions, derivatives

I was wondering if someone would be able to help me understand how to approach this question, as I'm unsure what it's saying.

The question is:

You are given a differentiable function $f$ : $R \to R$ which satisfies the equality, $$f(\exp(f(x))=f(x)$$

for all $x \in R$. Show that if $f'(x)$ doesn't equal 0, then

$$f'(\exp(f(x)))=\exp(-f(x))$$

Note:  This is meant to be $e$ to the power of $f(x)$ on the LHS, but I can't get it to write that, and $e$ to the power of $-f(x)$ on the RHS.

Any help with this questions would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Apply the chain rule. Try writing $e^x$ as $exp(x)$.

Comment: So am I meant to differentiate using the chain rule f(e^f(x)).  So let u = f(a), and let v = a, where a = e^f(x)?

Comment: Yes, differentiate the function $f \circ exp \circ f$.